# Discovering bluetooth devices on Android (example) isnt working

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

```
   final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                 BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                 BTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

   public void find(View view) {
       if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
           myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       }
       else {
            BTArrayAdapter.clear();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));    
        }    
   }
```

When pressing "findBtn" there is no any devices. The simple code at developer.android.com. How to discover correctly? Any mistakes in the code?
Example [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/bluetooth/bluetoothadapter/android-bluetooth-example/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before

[You can Look up to this app](https://github.com/dreamsparkx/GarageBluetooth)

[Or you can refer to this library](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary)